# How can I clean an egg from the windshield and from the body of a car?

Tags: cleaning, damage

Somebody very successfully egged (as I now learned the term for this obscene phenomenon) my car last night, while parked in an unknown neighborhood. Reports are coming that multiple cars were targeted in that area.

I'm saying "very successfully" because it looks as if the egg was beaten before being thrown. The egg yellow is uniformly spread. I expected there would be separate yolk and egg white areas.

It's likely not a disaster. It can be washed. My first fear was that somebody threw paint, and that even it could be washed from the windshield, any attempt to clean with thinner the body will result in even worse consequences.

It was a cool night, yet the egg already looked "cooked" after only 30-60 minutes.

How can I clean an egg from the windshield and from the body of a car?

Comment: Make sure that it did not travel into the air vents below the windscreen…

Comment: @SolarMike If these air vents were blocked, that would block fresh air from the passenger compartment, but the engine would not be starved; is that right?

Comment: @Sam the engine gets its air from under the hood or somewhere around the headlights. The top air vents are only used for air conditioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warm water.

If the egg is "cured" enough, a piece of wet cloth can be put over the damaged place until the egg matter softens enough.

Answer (score 1):

Wash it normally. Ensure you put some type of sealant back on it (like wax or what have you). You need to get it off your paint though, as it will damage it.